# What to cite for MSX6 survey?

Tags: astronomy

Here is my current dilemma: I used the data from [MSX6 Survey](http://irsa.ipac.caltech.edu/Missions/msx.html) and want to put a citation or some kind of acknowledgment but I can't seem to find any concrete paper or reference text to put in the paper. Any of you would know what paper to cite?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The appropriate thing to do is cite the catalog itself. Here it is in the ADS: "[MSX6C Infrared Point Source Catalog. The Midcourse Space Experiment Point Source Catalog Version 2.3](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2003yCat.5114....0E)."

The preferred format in the usual ApJ style is "Egan et al. 2003, VizieR Online Data Catalog, 5114, 0", but ADS can give you the [BibTex too](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-bib_query?bibcode=2003yCat.5114....0E&data_type=BIBTEX&db_key=AST&nocookieset=1).

Finally, note that the MSX people ask that you include the following acknowledgement in your paper (something which you don't strictly *need* to do, but which is nice):

> This research made use of data products from the Midcourse Space Experiment. Processing of the data was funded by the Ballistic Missile Defense Organization with additional support from NASA Office of Space Science. This research has also made use of the NASA/ IPAC Infrared Science Archive, which is operated by the Jet Propulsion Laboratory, California Institute of Technology, under contract with the National Aeronautics and Space Administration.

Comment: Great, thanks for the information. BibTex info will do the job via BibDesk.

Comment: You may wish to look at IPY's [How to Cite a Data Set](http://ipydis.org/data/citations.html) if you ever have need to generate a citation without ADS to help.  They map common bibliographic roles to similar roles by data archives.  There's a whole community of people from data archives, libraries, and journal publishers who are looking into trying to come up with better solutions to dealing with data citation and data provenance.